# Handbrake - automatically keep aspect ratio when downscaling?

Tags: video, video-conversion, handbrake, aspect-ratio

How can I in Handbrake 1.6 automatically keep the aspect ratio when downscaling a clip?

I found this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwiVjJwVawo and as you can see there used to be a check box for that:

[image: Old version of Handbrake]

But in my current version the same view is missing that box!?!?

[image: Handbrake 1.6]

I can of course calculate this manually but why, when a computer can do it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The option has been renamed to “Automatic”. If you hover over the checkbox, a tooltip appears stating:

> Keep Aspect Ratio maintains the original display aspect of the source.
> Disabling this may result in a stretched or squeezed picture.

[image: scrot]

Comment: But when that is checked I can't change the dimensions, can I?

Comment: Aspect ratio isn't the same as dimensions. I've not tested this, but if it's working as it should having this checked should just lock height and width so that changing one will change the other in the same ratio.